# How to find differences between two HTML text?

Tags: java

How to find the differences between the two HTML texts?

I need something similar to [Diff Patch Match](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

The problem with Diff Patch Match is that it finds the differences between two plain texts only and not the HTML texts.

Comment: what's the difference between html and regular texts?!

Comment: What is HTML then plain text? Are you looking for a tool that will diff rendered HTML?

Comment: Basically I have a screen in my application where I have a Rich text editor. An Admin User will enter text using RTE. User can enter different version of same text. So for eg. v1 be like "some text". v2 can be 'some text edited'. This can be plain text or html as it is a RTE. I need to find the different between these two versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the HTML tags from the text using some regular expression and then do a difference between them using Diff Patch Match library.
Please note that this will not find any differences in styles.

EDIT:
If you want to show the differences found also along with their styles , you could search for the differences in the modified text and parse around the text to find the HTML surrounding it and then use show the difference along with this HTML.

Comment: Yes, But here in this case after finding the differences, how will I apply the original styles?

Comment: There are two issues here 1) if you want to show the difference with style 2) if you want to show the differences in styles also, for example to show that somebody made a text BOLD in the new version. Do you want to do both ?

Comment: Ideally, yes. but if 2) is not possible at least I should be able to show the difference in style.

Comment: I updated my answer with how you can achieve 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the text using a library like [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) and then apply this diff

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Difftextfiledifferenceutility.htm) is what exactly you need.

**a.txt**

```
Hello

hi friends
```

**b.txt**

```
Hello world

hi
```

**Output**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>java Diff a.txt b.txt
>>>> Difference of file "a.txt" and file "b.txt".

>>>> 1 CHANGED FROM
Hello

hi friends
>>>>     CHANGED TO
Hello world

hi

>>>> End of differences.
```

Comment: I guess he wants to get differences in the html structure as well. Plain text comparison might see differences in that: `<html> <head> ... ` and `<html><head>... ` because of the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries) to process each your .html files.

Then use your favorite diff tool (eg. Diff Patch Match, windiff, ...) to compare the outputs of Html Tidy.